# JTDS tries (and fails) to recreate already-existing table on application start

Tags: sql-server, spring-data-jpa, jtds

I'm trying to write an application to connect to a MS SQL Server database.  The database already exists, the tables are already configured.  All I want to do is to connect my Java Spring app to the already-existing server.  However, when I try to do so, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: There is already an object named 'Customer' in the database.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeImpl(JtdsStatement.java:809) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.execute(JtdsStatement.java:1282) ~[jtds-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.10.Final.jar:5.1.10.Final]
... 87 common frames omitted
```

It seems like JTDS is trying to recreate my Customer table, and indeed if I delete the table and then run the application, it does indeed create a new table in my database called "Customer".  However, I can't drop my table on every application start (for obvious reasons) so I need to configure my application to connect to a table which already exists.  How do I do this?

Database appconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan("com.example.dbentity")
public class AppConfig {

@Value("${db.driver.class.name}")
private String dbDriverClassName;

@Value("${db.prefix}")
private String dbPrefix;

@Value("${db.url}")
private String dbUrl;

@Value("${db.name}")
private String dbName;

@Value("${db.username}")
private String dbUsername;

@Value("${db.password}")
private String dbPassword;

@Bean
public DataSource DataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName);
    String connectionUrl = dbPrefix + dbUrl + "/" +dbName;
    dataSource.setUrl(connectionUrl);
    dataSource.setUsername(dbUsername);
    dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate JdbcTemplate() {
    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate();
    template.setDataSource(DataSource());
    return template;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.dbentity");
    factory.setDataSource(DataSource());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
}
}
```

Configuration YAML:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: sample-application
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate

server:
  port: 8080
  max-http-header-size: 65536

db:
  driver:
    class:
      name: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
  prefix: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://
  url: example-server.net:1433
  name: example-db
  username: user
  password: password
```

Hibernate output:

```
2018-07-13 10:57:56.831  INFO 15336 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Loaded JDBC driver: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
2018-07-13 10:57:56.882  INFO 15336 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-07-13 10:57:56.901  INFO 15336 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
name: default
...]
2018-07-13 10:57:57.002  INFO 15336 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.10.Final}
2018-07-13 10:57:57.002  INFO 15336 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2018-07-13 10:57:57.006  INFO 15336 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2018-07-13 10:57:57.060  INFO 15336 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2018-07-13 10:57:57.531  INFO 15336 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
2018-07-13 10:57:57.672  INFO 15336 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000423: Disabling contextual LOB creation as JDBC driver reported JDBC version [3] less than 4
2018-07-13 10:57:58.754  WARN 15336 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property for Hibernate called `ddl-auto` where you can set whether Hibernate will **`create`** the schema on start, **`validate`** the schema that's already there, or do no validation of the existing schema.

What you want to do is to just use **`validate`** (or **`none`**).

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate) for how to configure this in `Spring Boot` and [here](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-spring) (i.e. the `hibernateProperties`) for how to do this in `Vanilla Spring`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  I'm going to add my configuration YAML to the OP.

Comment: Can you also post the hibernate prior to your error?

Comment: I added the Hibernate output in my console above the error message (not including the Spring output)

Comment: Oh another question I had forgotten to ask which you answered. It looks like you're using Spring Boot! That means you can remove the `AppConfig` class entirely! Spring Boot will configure those beans for you. When you have them there it will override the default beans and that's why it's not working. You'll still need the `validate` inyour SB config

Comment: Yeah, actually I had a colleague help me out with this issue, and she said the same thing and that's what  ended up fixing it (I had to add a couple other fields as well that I didn't have before, but I don't think that's generalizeable enough to make it worth commenting here),  I'll accept your answer.  Thanks!